# issue with submitting form MS SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Hello I have an issue submitting a form into SQL database I Am getting the following error

I am not sure if it is something to do with sessions as i am trying to get the user who is logged in to be submitted with the form so that I can filter it later to show only details to this specific user.

ERROR SHOWN BELOW

```
   1NULL 23string(477) "INSERT INTO tbl_Impact (Schema_ID, Stakeholder_ID, Intended_Changes, Investment_Type_ID, Value_of_Investment, Summary, Outcomes_Description, Outcomes_Indicator, Outcomes_Source, Outcomes_Quantity, Outcomes_Duration, Outcomes_Start, Outcomes_Financial_Proxy, Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy, Deadweight, Displacement, Attribution, Drop_Off, UserID) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '1', '11', '11', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '')" 45object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(477) "INSERT INTO tbl_Impact (Schema_ID, Stakeholder_ID, Intended_Changes, Investment_Type_ID, Value_of_Investment, Summary, Outcomes_Description, Outcomes_Indicator, Outcomes_Source, Outcomes_Quantity, Outcomes_Duration, Outcomes_Start, Outcomes_Financial_Proxy, Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy, Deadweight, Displacement, Attribution, Drop_Off, UserID) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '1', '11', '11', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '')" }
```

Code

```
  public function createSchema(){

 echo "1";
         //stage 1
          $stakeholder = htmlspecialchars($_POST['stakeholderTextbox']);
          $changes = htmlspecialchars($_POST['changesTextbox']);


         //stage 2
          $typeOfInvestment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['typeInvestmentTextbox']);
          $valueOfInvestment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['valueInvestmentTextbox']);
          $summary = htmlspecialchars($_POST['summaryTextbox']);


         //stage 3
          $description = htmlspecialchars($_POST['descriptionTextbox']);
          $indicator = htmlspecialchars($_POST['indicatorTextbox']);
          $source = htmlspecialchars($_POST['sourceTextbox']);
          $quantity = htmlspecialchars($_POST['quantityTextbox']);
          $duration = htmlspecialchars($_POST['durationTextbox']); 
          $outcomesStar = htmlspecialchars($_POST['outcomesTextbox']);
          $financialProxy = htmlspecialchars($_POST['financialProxyTextbox']);
          $valueProxy = htmlspecialchars($_POST['valueProxyTextbox']);
         // $source2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['source2Textbox']);

          //stage 4
          $deadweight = htmlspecialchars($_POST['deadweightTextbox']);
          $displacement = htmlspecialchars($_POST['displacementTextbox']);
          $attribution = htmlspecialchars($_POST['attributionTextbox']);
          $dropOff = htmlspecialchars($_POST['dropOffTextbox']);

          $userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
var_dump($userID);

            echo "2";
          /* $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_Impact (Schema_ID, Stakeholder_ID, Intended_Changes, Investment_Type_ID, Value_of_Investment, Summary, Outcomes_Description, Outcomes_Indicator, Outcomes_Source, Outcomes_Quantity, Outcomes_Duration, Outcomes_Start, Outcomes_Financial_Proxy, Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy, Deadweight, Displacement, Attribution, Drop_Off,  UserID) 
                         VALUES (NULL, '$stakeholder', '$changes', '$typeOfInvestment', '$valueOfInvestment', '$summary', '$description', '$indicator', '$source', '$quantity', '$duration', '$outcomesStar', '$financialProxy', '$valueProxy', '$source2', '$deadweight', '$displacement', '$attribution', '$dropOff', '$userID')"; */

                         $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_Impact (Schema_ID, Stakeholder_ID, Intended_Changes, Investment_Type_ID, Value_of_Investment, Summary, Outcomes_Description, Outcomes_Indicator, Outcomes_Source, Outcomes_Quantity, Outcomes_Duration, Outcomes_Start, Outcomes_Financial_Proxy, Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy, Deadweight, Displacement, Attribution, Drop_Off,  UserID) 
                         VALUES (NULL, '$stakeholder', '$changes', '$typeOfInvestment', '$valueOfInvestment', '$summary', '$description', '$indicator', '$source', '$quantity', '$duration', '$outcomesStar', '$financialProxy', '$valueProxy',  '$deadweight', '$displacement', '$attribution', '$dropOff', '$userID')";
echo "3";
var_dump($sqlQuery);
                $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); 
                echo "4";
                $statement->execute(); 
                // $count = $statement-rowCount();
                echo "5";

                var_dump($statement);
    }
```

Thanks

[TABLE IN MS SQL DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Quw.png)

Comment: wow - the above is vulnerable to SQL Injection and there is no sanity checking of variables being available in the POST array. You use a prepared statement in one place but directly embed variables in another ( making it vulnerable ). The image is unreadable "as is" - but the SQL ends incorrectly regardless `'$userID)"` should be `'$userID')"` and `$attribution'` should be `'$attribution'` ~ possibly others

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am aware it is vulnerable to SQL but i am just trying to input data into the database as I have been having many issues once done then I can secure it, if you drag and drop the image into the address bar it will show up.

Comment: the image above showing the error message is way too small to decipher... If you were to properly use prepared statements now you would not have hit this particular issue I suspect ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I  have amended '$userID' and '$attribution' and i still get this error ---------------

Comment: Please post the full error that you're getting now, preferrably as text. Images make it really hard to read and diagnose.

Comment: Testing then securing tends to cause more headaches. If you properly prepare and bind your statements now, **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues like this one again.**

Comment: I have just posted the error

Comment: You have 19 columns and 20 values. Figure out if you're missing a column or passing too many values, or still missing a quote. Again, parameter binding means no more messing with quoting.

Comment: Also, checking for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) eliminates a lot of the guesswork when dealing with query failures.

Comment: Same error :( :(

Comment: Your var_dump isn't an error, it's the details of your statement. Actually check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to get the error. Please [edit] your post with your current query. Verify that you're passing in the same number of columns and values, and that (if you're not using parameter binding) every single variable has a quote. In the query above, you're also missing a single quote before `$quantity`

Comment: What do i need to do to get PDO errors please? can you send me the code to put in i am sorry i am new on  PHP also I have pasted the new query above.

Comment: I have added the table which is in MS SQL table

Comment: I can only suggest reading the link I posted. You still have a column/value mismatch: 19 columns in the first set of parenthesis, 20 values in the second set. The query definitely won't work until you fix it. By comparing the two, `$source2` is the extra value, so either remove it or specify its column.

Comment: Stop trying to test all 19/20 fields at once. If you are just testing start with a query that just adds 1 field and keep adding one by one until you get to the one that has the issue.

Comment: @aynber - I have removed $source2 and the issue still there i am not sure what else to do please see above the new code with source2 being removed.

Comment: The query now looks correct as far as syntax, but I couldn't tell you why it's not working. You can copy the generated query (shown in your statement dump) and run it directly in the database to see if it works there, and also check for PDO errors, with the code at the link I posted.

Comment: It worked, the issue was UserID was a uniqueidentifier so i could not do pass values to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query statement is wrong. Please replace your query statement with the following

```
 $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_Impact (Schema_ID, Stakeholder_ID, Intended_Changes, Investment_Type_ID, Value_of_Investment, Summary, Outcomes_Description, Outcomes_Indicator, Outcomes_Source, Outcomes_Quantity, Outcomes_Duration, Outcomes_Start, Outcomes_Financial_Proxy, Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy, Deadweight, Displacement, Attribution, Drop_Off,  UserID) 
                         VALUES (NULL, '$stakeholder', '$changes', '$typeOfInvestment', '$valueOfInvestment', '$summary', '$description', '$indicator', '$source', $quantity', '$duration', '$outcomesStar', '$financialProxy', '$valueProxy', '$source2', '$deadweight', '$displacement', $attribution', '$dropOff', '$userID')";
```

Comment: I have changed it and it is still come up with the same error, I have fixed $attribution' should be '$attribution' as well but still coming up with same error

Comment: can you paste the error. Only error not the echo statements.

Comment: also I believe you need to chanck each field datatype. As you are posting everything in string. I could not be able to open your database table file/image.

Comment: 45object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(476) "INSERT INTO

Comment: I am passing it as int to aviod any filetype issues but it is still not accepting it, database image should be working fine now please let me know if it is not working.